# PhP check if variable of loop equals variable of cell

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check if the `$i` variable of the loop equals the values of my table cells in my MySQL database. I can't make it work. I'm not that good at PHP so I would like your help.
Note: the result1-20 cells are declared as integers in the database.
Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');
  $mysql_hostname = "localhost"; 
  $mysql_user     = "root";
  $mysql_password = "root";
  $mysql_database = "db";

  $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Connection Error");
  mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("DB Error");

  $display = mysql_query("SELECT drawNo,drawTime,LEFT(drawTime,10) ,RIGHT(drawTime,9) FROM draw ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", $bd);


  while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($display) )
  {
    echo"<td>$row[drawNo]</th><th> " . $row['LEFT(drawTime,10)'] . "</td><td> " . $row['RIGHT(drawTime,9)'] . "</td>";
?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" style="text-align:center">
<?php

    $i=1;
    $result=0;
    while($i<81) {
      if($i%10==1) {
        echo"<tr>".PHP_EOL;
      }
      echo "<td>".$i."</td>".PHP_EOL;
      $i++;
      if($i%10==1) {
        echo"</tr>".PHP_EOL;
      }

    }

    if($row[result.$i]==(int)$i) {
      echo "found!";
    }

  }

?>
</table>
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` extensions, they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: I know but that's not my main problem. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Which value in the table cell are you trying to check? Your question is not quite clear.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to check $row[result.$i] equals i then do stuff,else do other stuff

Comment: Where are you setting `$i`?

Comment: Just before the while loop

Comment: The problem is with `result.$i` - what is setting `result`? You probably want `'result'.$i` to concat the two strings.

Comment: The problem I seem to encounter is that PhP won't compare the $i variable with the column value, both of these values are integers so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.Thank you for you help

Comment: The query result `$row[]` will contain the keys `drawNo`, `drawTime`, `LEFT(drawTime,10)` ,`RIGHT(drawTime,9)`. It will **not** contain any key resembling `result...`. You need to provide a better explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I will try to explain myself better. I have this database(pic provided)http://prntscr.com/4cg7hj . And I created a simple php html table that creates this table http://prntscr.com/4cg7rl . I want to check if the values of the result1-20 cells equals the value of the html table cell.I hope you can understand better now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to extract the 20 values from the database. You already have one query, so you could just fetch all columns and extract the `result..` columns from there. You also need to extract the date and time using PHP:

```php
<?php

  $display = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM draw ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1', $bd);
  if (!$display) {
    /* Error: Query failed. */
  }
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($display);
  if (!$row) {
    /* Error: No results. */
  }

  $drawdate = substr ($row['drawTime'], 0, 10);
  $drawtime = substr ($row['drawTime'], -9);

  $results = array();
  for ($i = 1; $i < 21; $i++) {
    $results[$row["result$i"]] = true;
  }
```

For example, if `result2` of the first row contains `11` then, when `$i == 2`, the code will set `$results[11] = true`. Now you can loop from 1 to 80, and check if the current number is set in `$results`:

```php
  echo <<<HTML
<table>
 <thead><tr><th>$row[drawNo]</th><th>$drawdate</th><th> $drawtime</th>
 <tbody>

HTML;

  for ($i = 1; $i < 81; $i++) {
    if ($i%10 === 1) {
      echo "   <tr>";
    }
    /* Set $class if number $i is set in $results */
    $class = isset ($results[$i]) ? ' class=found' : '';
    echo "<td$class>$i</td>";
    if ($i%10 === 0) {
      echo "</tr>\n";
    }
  }

  echo <<<HTML
 </tbody>
</table>

HTML;
```

Then you add a style for `.found` in your style sheet:

```css
td.found { color: green; }
```

Or in an inline style:

```html
<style type="text/css">

  td.found { color: green; }

</style>
```

**Note also** that the mysql extension is deprecated and no longer maintained. New code should be written using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately this didn't work, here is my code so far and I'll provide a screenshot to get a better idea.
Code: http://pastebin.com/MM2VzHQv
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4cgu7s
Anyhow, thank you for taking the time to answer my problems.

Comment: Does the table always contain 4 by 20 values, and do you want to match those against the 80 table cells?

Comment: I want to check if my db result1-20 cells value equals the $i value and if so change the color of the $i value to green else change the color of the $i value to red.That's all I'm trying to do really.

Comment: @akad0: Gotcha. I re-wrote my answer.

Comment: Thank so much! That did the trick. I'm inexperienced with PhP so thank you so very much :)